# Remove Gnome style from Eclipse Luna

Tags: linux, eclipse, gtk, themes, look-and-feel

I've installed Eclipse Luna on my Debian machine and recognized that Eclipse looked like all other Gnome applications.

I had Gnome installed, but I'm using KDE and don't like applications to look like Gnome.

I removed all gnome libraries, but Eclipse still looks the same. Is there any way to remove the Gnome theme from Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that there is no such a way to totally get rid of Gnome theme from Eclipse, but you can install some compatible tools to make KDE render appearance built on GTK, for example, `gtk3-engines-oxygen` and `gtk2-engines-oxygen` (Oxygen is your KDE desktop theme).

If you are using other themes, you can use the following command to search out the exact software name:

```
aptitude search gtk3-engines
```

Comment: So, you mean you have both GNome and KDE installed? I think if you have native GTK3 installed, gtk3-engines plugins don't work at all.

Comment: No I have both `gtkX-engines-oxygen` packages installed, but no gnome one. But Eclipse is written in Java so I don't think that those native packages have effect on Eclipse

Comment: That's really weird. My Laptop OS is Debian 7 testing with KDE, gtkX-engines-oxygen works fine for me. Sorry for not helping you out this problem~